# Do I use partial fractions? How to set it up?

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, divergent-series, partial-fractions

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+2}\right)$$

Comment: Please, would you mind using latex so that we can better assist you. It is quite a challenge, and annoying, trying to understand what you wrote.

Comment: I can't figure how to use it. I'm sorry.

Comment: @DonAnselmo It's helpful to include a [link to the MathJax guide](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), rather than just telling people to use something they've possibly never heard of.

Comment: @T. Bongers Two things: 1. he can ask if he has not heard of something. 2. What is google for?

Comment: @Itzel I have transcribed what I understood to be your question. Please verify that I have done so accurately.

Comment: @DonAnselmo Especially with new users, I think it's more important to be courteous, welcoming and helpful, rather than brusque and abrasive.

Comment: @T. Bongers what is your definition of brusque? Have I been brusque with the asker?

Comment: @Neal yes thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You don't want to use partial fractions here. Look at the partial sums:
$$
s_k=\sum_{n=1}^k \left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+2} \right)
$$

Try to come up a closed formula for $s_k$ (something that depends upon just $k$) and then look at

$$
\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}s_k.
$$

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This is a telescoping series whose sum is 3/2.

Comment: I knew that I need to know how to step it up.

Comment: If you knew that, why did you ask divergent or convergent?  Please ask the question you need an answer to.

Comment: I did I asked if my A/n + b/n+2 was right and what would I set n equal to.

Comment: @Itzel Partial fractions is used to break apart fractions.  For example, you may use partial fractions to rewrite $\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$ in the form $\frac{A}{n} + \frac{B}{n+1}$ for some $A$ and $B$.  Your expression, however, is already split up, so there is no need to think about partial fractions.  There is no real set up in this problem, it just happens to work itself out.

Comment: @tylerc0816 thanks. Just needed to know that.

Answer (score 0):

Your left side has no free variables-$n$ is a dummy that you sum over.  The right side has $n$ free, so they cannot be equal.  The left side is either a number (here $\frac 32)$ or nonsense.  The point of the comments about telescoping series is that most of the terms cancel.  What is left?