# Quick Telescopic Series Question

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, derivatives

So I was given the following prompt when I was studying for a test:

"Determine the sum of the following convergent series: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+2})$"

I'm a bit confused about what the setup would look like here. I understand the setup for the other type of geometric series (where the sum of the series is equal to the first term divided by $1-$ the common ratio), and I also understand that the formula for this series looks like the following: $S_n=b_1-b_{n+1}$, but I'm confused about what that formula would look like in this specific context. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Write out the first 7 terms of the series and see what cancels.

Comment: You can find several related or identical questions with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum_%7Bn%3D1%7D%5E%5Cinfty%20(%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bn%7D-%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bn%2B2%7D)%24): https://math.stackexchange.com/q/589065/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1063724/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2020577/42969

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $$\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+2}=\left (\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)+ \left( \frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+2}\right)$$
Now you do telescoping for two togather.